# Can you upload an image from a mobile phone html page on Node-red?

Tags: ibm-watson, node-red, visual-recognition

I'm trying to take an image from a phone and then put it through Watson Visual Recognition on Node-Red.

I've been loading my URL on my phone, and it's able to take an image, but then instantly crashes.

Does anyone have any experience in this? Thanks

My node-red flow is here

```
[{"id":"d2139149.736cb","type":"visual-recognition-v3","z":"12c7584.82dbca8","name":"Classify Meter","apikey":"","image-feature":"classifyImage","lang":"en","x":652.107177734375,"y":757.9999923706055,"wires":[["603c48c7.3144f8","8f4f26d2.549338","a862f46a.96305"]]},{"id":"4a935442.0b7efc","type":"http in","z":"12c7584.82dbca8","name":"","url":"/recophone","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":115,"y":733.4404983520508,"wires":[["f235ab46.9552a8"]]},{"id":"1c640d2d.20b8b3","type":"http response","z":"12c7584.82dbca8","name":"HTTP Response","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":1097.33349609375,"y":719.3928298950195,"wires":[]},{"id":"f235ab46.9552a8","type":"switch","z":"12c7584.82dbca8","name":"Check Url","property":"payload.imageurl","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"null"},{"t":"else"}],"checkall":"false","outputs":2,"x":311.5714111328125,"y":727.4404907226562,"wires":[["7de01baf.d96a2c"],["9b629cc.7379fe"]]},{"id":"603c48c7.3144f8","type":"template","z":"12c7584.82dbca8","name":"Report","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"html","syntax":"mustache","template":"<html>\n<head><title>Watson Visual Recognition on Node-RED</title></head>\n<style> \nbody {background-color: white;}\nh1   {text-align: center;}\nh2   {color: black; text-align: center; font-family: verdana; font-size: 30px;}\np    {color:black; text-align: center; font-family: verdana; font-size: 15px;}\ntable {color:black; text-align: center; font-family: verdana; font-size: 15px;}\nform {color:black; text-align: center; font-family: verdana; font-size: 15px;}\n</style>\n<body>\n<h1><img src=\"http://www.rousseau.com.pt/imagens/estudos/IBM_logo_blue_thumb1.png\">\n<img src=\"https://images.reevoo.com/retailers/Center/NPOWR/brand/260x200.png\"> </h1>\n<h2>Node-RED Watson Visual Recognition output</h2>\n<p>Analyzed image: {{payload}}<br/><img src=\"{{payload}}\" height='100'/></p>\n<table border='1' align=\"center\"> \n   <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Score</th></tr></thead>\n{{#result.images.0.classifiers.0.classes}}\n  <tr><td><b>{{class}}</b></td><td><i>{{score}}</i></td></tr>\n{{/result.images.0.classifiers.0.classes}}\n</table>\n<form  action=\"{{req._parsedUrl.pathname}}\">\n    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Try again\"/>\n</form>\n</body>\n</html>","x":903.7618408203125,"y":756.726203918457,"wires":[["1c640d2d.20b8b3"]]},{"id":"9b629cc.7379fe","type":"change","z":"12c7584.82dbca8","name":"Convert Url","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"payload.imageurl","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":459.33343505859375,"y":757.2500228881836,"wires":[["d2139149.736cb"]]},{"id":"8f4f26d2.549338","type":"function","z":"12c7584.82dbca8","name":"get labels","func":"//var labels = msg.result.images[0].classifiers[0].classes;\nvar confidence = msg.result.images[0].classifiers[0].classes;\n//msg.payload = labels.map(function(i){\n //  return i.class;\nmsg.payload = confidence.map(function(i){\nreturn i.class + \" \" + i.score;\n//msg.payload = confidence.map(function(i){\n  //return i.score;\n  \n});\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":897.66650390625,"y":795.1071243286133,"wires":[["e10c122c.626fd"]]},{"id":"e10c122c.626fd","type":"debug","z":"12c7584.82dbca8","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"payload","x":1082.428466796875,"y":791.726203918457,"wires":[]},{"id":"a862f46a.96305","type":"debug","z":"12c7584.82dbca8","name":"","active":false,"console":"false","complete":"result","x":901.3629150390625,"y":832.3452758789062,"wires":[]},{"id":"df542a47.1a7088","type":"inject","z":"12c7584.82dbca8","name":"URL","topic":"","payload":"http://visual-recognition-demo.mybluemix.net/images/samples/2.jpg","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":474.73809814453125,"y":795.75,"wires":[["d2139149.736cb"]]},{"id":"7de01baf.d96a2c","type":"template","z":"12c7584.82dbca8","name":"File UploadGet Image URL","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"html","syntax":"mustache","template":"<html>\n<head>\n    <style>\nbody {background-color: white;}\nh1   {text-align: center;}\nh2   {color: black; text-align: center; font-family: verdana; font-size: 30px;}\nh3   {color:black; text-align: center; font-family: verdana; font-size: 15px;}\nform {color:black; text-align: center; font-family: verdana; font-size: 15px;}\n</style>\n<title>Npower Meter Watson Visual Recognition font-family: \"Playfair Display\", serif;\nfont-size: 32px;text-align: left; </title> </head>\n<body>\n<h1> <img src=\"http://www.rousseau.com.pt/imagens/estudos/IBM_logo_blue_thumb1.png\">\n<img src=\"https://images.reevoo.com/retailers/Center/NPOWR/brand/260x200.png\"> </h1> \n \n <h2>  Welcome to this demo on identifying Meter Issues via images </h2>\n <h3> Select an image URL</h3>\n<form  action=\"{{req._parsedUrl.pathname}}\">\n    //Code for taking picture from phone\n<form action=\"/action_page.php\">\n  <input type=\"file\" name=\"pic\" accept=\"image/*\">\n  <input type=\"submit\">\n   <img src=\"http://static.flickr.com/3087/2648843542_3101f132ec.jpg\" height='200'/>\n    <img src=\"http://static.flickr.com/3281/2719178040_e80447902d.jpg\" height='200'/>\n    <img src=\"http://static.flickr.com/2308/2218597585_410d3c9148.jpg\" height='200'/>\n    <img src=\"http://static.flickr.com/3072/2439552803_ed8b7d6ab1.jpg\" height='200'/>\n<br/><b>Copy above image location URL or enter any image URL:</b><br/>\n    <input type=\"text\" name=\"imageurl\"/>\n    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Analyze\"/>\n</form>\n</body>\n</html>\n","x":843.5714111328125,"y":716.5833435058594,"wires":[["1c640d2d.20b8b3"]]},{"id":"7bd12438.024544","type":"comment","z":"12c7584.82dbca8","name":"Phone Upload","info":"","x":110,"y":682,"wires":[]}]
```

Comment: Update the question with details of how it crashes?

Comment: It doesn't crash as such, it just fails up upload and says 'Cannot Post /Upload.php

Comment: I've put debug tabs on everywhere in my flow and I'm not getting any sign of a payload.

Comment: That  still doesn't help  much, there isn't an http-in with a path set `/Upload.php` anywhere in your flow. Also the only http-in is set to process GET requests not POSTs and to handle `/recophone` where as all the form elements in the template point to `/action_page.php` (and have an extra form tag.

Comment: So the above method was initially created so users could enter a URL on the webpage, and then that URL would be converted to a payload and put through visual recognition. That worked great. It's the upload file section which isn't producing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Camera node that is included in the node-red-contrib-browser-utils package.
To install it either run

```
npm install node-red-contrib-browser-utils
```

or go your Node-red instance -> Menu (top-right) -> Manage palette -> Install -> Search for node-red-contrib-browser utils

More info [on the NPM registry page](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-browser-utils)